# Like 'resize', but for lengths

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Suppose I'm drawing a rectangle on screen. I can *resize* it — change its length and/or width to make it bigger or smaller overall. Now suppose I'm drawing a line, which I can make shorter or longer. Is there a word describing this action, other than *resizing* the line? It's one-dimensional and doesn't really have a size, and there's no such word as *relengthing*.

Comment: Why can't you 'resize' a line? You are changing the size of it by altering the length?

Comment: Because lines don't have sizes. They have no 'bulk', no 'substance' which can have a size.

Comment: Your rectangle has a two-dimensional size, measured in (say) square centimetres. A solid has a three-dimensional size, measured in cubic centimetres. A line has a one-dimensional size, measured in centimetres. You can resize a line.

Comment: How about "*rescale*"?

Comment: My salary is only one dimensional, but it certainly has a size.

Comment: It's not like I can't see at all where you're coming from, it's just that languages don't work that way. *Resize* cannot be used for lines if and only if we don't use it for lines. But we do use it for lines, so using it for lines is fine. That is because *resize* does not mean "change size". In and of itself it has no meaning at all. It only has the meaning we assign to it. That meaning can be "change size", or "change length", or "change volume", or "change the color of the leftmost cat from lilac to orange", or some of these, or all of these, or none.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I think most people would understand what he was trying to say if he used 'resize.' That doesn't mean its completely correct, but the meaning would get across to the audience.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Show me something like a university/college textbook referring to "resizing lines" or "line size".

Comment: @DanBron: Does a line have a scale?

Comment: Einpoklum, yes. Picture a ruler.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Can you back that up with link to some appropriate 'autoritative' text mentioning lines being "resized"? I kind of doubt what you're saying. Also, when people refer to the sizes of 3-dimensional objects, it seems to me they usually refer to their projected 2D area or 2D surface area (e.g. "How big is your room?" - would you give an answer in square meters, or cubmic meters?)

Comment: @DanBron: The length of a line has a scale, not the line...

Comment: @einpoklum first off, "line size" has nothing to do with anything here. This question is about *resize* the verb, not *size* the noun. Let's stay on topic. Second off, show me something like a university/college textbook referring to "lilac car" or "salty hamburger". Just because you're unable to do so does not prove anything at all. It's a complete red herring.

Comment: @AndyBlankertz: Salaries have heights, not sizes. Your salary isn't big or small, it's high or low.

Answer (score 5):

The verb you want is *resize*.

You can resize many things:

- [images](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/resize-a-picture-using-paint)
- [Vectors in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)
- [DOM elements, using CSS](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize)
- [ext4 filesystems](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ext4grow.html)
- [A window](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001478.htm)

And many others.

Some of these things are inherently two-dimensional, some are not. All of these things are virtual, computer-based things. You typically do not resize physical things, but in a computerized environment anything can be resized.

Comment: Images, DOM elements and windows are obviously 2-dimensional. A vector has a size because its elements each have a size - in bytes. Same goes for an ext4 filesystem (which can also be thought of as taking area on a disk). So, these examples are not relevant. None of them is like a one-dimensiona line.

Comment: @einpoklum A vector has a size in bytes. A line has a size in whatever units you want to measure it in. The number of dimensions of the object isn't relevant.

Comment: Also I object to your notion that a vector in C++ is multi-dimensional. It is not. And a filesystem is conceptually linear as well.

Comment: Just ask youself this: Can you have a vector of nulls?

Comment: Being 'linear' means being somewhat like a line, not exactly like a line. A straight road is linear but it's not a line - it has width. If a filesystem was entirely like a line it could not "take up space" on disk.

Comment: You can have a vector of nulls. Why not? A length is a kind of size, especially in a computerized world where you need a generic term like "resize".

Comment: Umm, I meant a vector of `void`s, sorry.

Comment: I don't see where you're going with the `void` thing. Let's say you can: then it's the same as the `nulls`. Let's say you can't: So what? Just because I can't have a vector of `purple` or `void` doesn't mean a vector isn't one-dimensional and its _size_ is its _length_ and you _resize_ it.

Comment: Actually, yes, it does mean that. Because the element size is another dimension of the vector, in addition to its length. Think of it as an arrangement of identical rectangles along a line. The line is uni-dimensional, but the collection of blocks is not.

Comment: Here's another, unrelated argument to why "resize" is the right word. When you resize a rectangle, you can (as you said the answer) change its length or its width. You don't need to change both, but you _can_ change both. The total area of the rectangle might be the same, might not. No matter what the transformation, it's all just "resize". You don't "rewidth", "relength", or "resize", depending on how it changes. There's just "resize". But I suspect I'm wasting my time trying to convince you. Good luck on whatever neologism you come up with.